# Why is the 4+1 architecture model view named "4+1"?

Tags: architecture, naming, history

Why are use-cases counted separately from the other views in the [4+1 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model)?
How are use-cases different from others views?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [4+1 approach to software architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/233257/209774) has 4 different but complementary views on the systems **internals**.

The 5th view (+1) differs from the others, as it’s about the system’s **externals**: the uses cases are about the goals of the system’s actors and how the system fits in the larger picture.

***Not related**: One could wonder why it’s not called 1+4 instead of 4+1, considering that the other views are difficult to envisage without knowing anything of the goals, the user’s expectations and the needs to address. I guess it’s because it’s called the “4+1 architectural view models” and not the “1+4 software engineering view models” ;-)*